# How do I access chain state data from a contract?

Tags: rust, substrate, rust-ink

Ho do I access storages or constants in a substrate chain from !ink smart contract? For example, in the chain, the timestamp(in Moment) is set as an extrinsic. How do I access the timestamp and put the variable in the smart contract?

`let timestamp_now: u128: <access to chain when function is being called>`

[image: Image of the timestamp]

Comment: Other than timestamp(https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.block_timestamp.html) and block number(https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.block_number.html) I am unable to find in the documentation on how to get storage/constant from chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can check https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/ Which provides functions as `block_number` and `block_timestamp`

ink! documentation in https://github.com/paritytech/ink#table-of-contents

Comment: As per my first comment in the question, the only items that can be queried from chain are timestamp and block number. I am interested to know on how can I access other chain data or storage that are made available through the pallets.

Comment: Still, other than block_number and timestamp which I have mentioned in my comments, there is no way to get the chain state data.